# How to create a Roblox game where the player has to guess a randomly generated pin?

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

So, I've been working on this for the past week. I have tried everything (based on the knowledge I know) and yet nothing... my code didn't work the first time, the second time, the third time... the forth... etc... at the end, I let frustration take control of me and I ended up deleting the whole script. Luckily not the parts and models, otherwise I'm really screwed...

I need to create a game in which I have to create a keypad of sorts, at first I thought GUI would work... no, it needs to be SurfaceGUI, which I don't know how to handle well... Anyway, I needed to create a keypad using SurfaceGUI, and display it on a separate screen, as a typical keypad would...

The Player would first have to enter an "initial" number, meaning in order to enter the randomly generated number he first needed to input the static pin in order to "log in," after that, then he would try to guess the number...

I've literally tried everything I could but nothing... It's mainly because of my lack of experience in LUA, I'm more advanced in Python and barely know a thing in Java... If someone could assist me on how to do this, I would appreciate it greatly

Answer (score 1):

First, download [this](https://www.mediafire.com/file/6ijswisuo0mc8ie/PINFile.rbxm/file) and put it in a ScreenGui in StarterGui. Then, use the following `LocalScript` placed inside the PIN frame:

```lua
-- Script settings

local len = 4 -- replace this as needed...
local regen = false -- determines whether PIN will regenerate after a failed attempt
local regmes = "Enter PIN..." -- start message of PIN pad
local badmes = "Wrong PIN!" -- message displayed when PIN is wrong
local success = "Correct PIN!" -- message displayed when PIN is right


-- Script workings

local pin = script.Parent
local top = pin.Top
local txt = top.Numbers
local nums = top.NumKeys
local pin
local stpin
local nms
txt.Text = regmes
local see = game:GetStorage("ReplicatedStorage").PINActivate
local function activate()
    if pin.Visible then
        pin.Visible = false
        for _, btn in pairs(nums:GetChildren()) do
            btn.Active = false
        end
        return
    else
        pin.Visible = true
        for _, btn in pairs(nums:GetChildren()) do
            btn.Active = true
        end
        return
    end
end
local function rand()
    math.randomseed(os.time) -- better random numbers this way
    return tostring(math.floor(math.random(0,9.9)))
end
local function gen()
    nms = {rand()}
    for i=2, len, 1 do
        nms[#nms+1]=rand()
    end
    stpin = nms[1]
    for i=2, #nms, 1 do
        stpin = stpin..nms[i]
    end
    pin = tonumber(stpin) -- converts the number string into an actual number
end
gen()
local function activate(str)
    if tonumber(str) ~= pin then
        txt.Text = badmes
        wait(2)
        txt.Text = regmes
        if regen then
            gen()
            wait(0.1)
        end
        return
    else
        txt.Text = success
        wait(2)
        activate()
        -- insert code here...
    end
end
for _, btn in pairs(nums:GetChildren()) do
    btn.Activated:Connect(function()
        if txt.Text == "Wrong PIN!" then return end
        txt.Text = txt.Text..btn.Text
        if string.len(txt.Text) >= len then
            activate(txt.Text)
        end
        wait(0.1)
    end)
end
see.OnClientEvent:Connect(activate)
```

And in a Script put this:

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local see = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").PINActivate
local plr
-- replace Event with something like Part.Touched
Event:Connect(function(part)
    if part.Parent.Head then
        plr = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
        see:FireClient(plr)
    end
end)
```

What this will do is bring up a `ScreenGui` for only that player so they can enter the PIN, and they can close it as well. You can modify as needed; have a great day! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way, try this
First, Create a GUI in StarterGui, then, Create a textbox and postion it, after that, create a local script inside and type this.

```
local Password = math.random(1000, 9999)

print(Password)
game.ReplicatedStorage.Password.Value = Password

script.Parent.FocusLost:Connect(function(enter)
    if enter then
        if script.Parent.Text == tostring(Password) then
            print("Correct!")
            script.Parent.BorderColor3 = Color3.new(0, 255, 0)
            Password = math.random(1000, 9999)
            game.ReplicatedStorage.Correct1:FireServer()
            print(Password)
            game.ReplicatedStorage.Password.Value = Password
        else
            print("wrong!")
            print(script.Parent.Text)
            script.Parent.BorderColor3 = Color3.new(255, 0, 0)
        end
    end
end)
```

That's all in the textbox.
Or if you want a random username script, create a textlabel, then, create a local script in the textlabel and type in this.

```
local UserText = script.Parent
local Username = math.random(1,10)

while true do
    if Username == 1 then
        UserText.Text = "John"
    elseif Username == 2 then
        UserText.Text = "Thomas"
    elseif Username == 3 then
        UserText.Text = "Raymond"
    elseif Username == 4 then
        UserText.Text = "Ray"
    elseif Username == 5 then
        UserText.Text = "Tom"
    elseif Username == 6 then
        UserText.Text = "Kai"
    elseif Username == 7 then
        UserText.Text = "Lloyd"
    elseif Username == 8 then
        UserText.Text = "Jay"
    elseif Username == 9 then
        UserText.Text = "User"
    else
        UserText.Text = "Guest"
    end
    wait()
end
```

All of those if statments are checking what username has been chosen. I have made a roblox game like this recently, so I just took all the script from the game.

If you want to check out my game, [Click Here](https://web.roblox.com/games/11455612774/Computer-PIN-Cracking-Simulator)